# Работа с видео через js

Tags: javascript

У меня есть определенный код js который будет ставить видео на паузу и убирать её, т.е. ничего сложного, примерно так:

```
if (!video[0].paused) {
  video[0].pause();
}
```

Обратная смена происходит подобным образом, но как видно я обращаюсь к первому блоку видео, хотя на странице их может быть несколько:

```
let video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
```

Вообщем обычно клики будет происходить на субтитры, но видео будет в одном из блоков рядом, и я пытался придумать как мне найти необходимое видео. Есть идеи как это можно сделать или кто-то уже делал?
Если очень упростить, то мне необходимо определить видео по клику на субтитры. Как-то так.

Да всякие поиски по классу и подобное мне не подходит, работать будет только через js, и единственное что известно это то что видео будет где-то рядом, всё, так что привязки которые работают через клас который известен заранее мне неподходят.

Comment: Было бы полезно, если бы вы привели пример вашей разметки.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko разметки??
Всмысле верстка??
Ну её нету, я пишу расширения для google chrome, поэтому единственное, что есть это js код, вёрстка может быть любая, зайди на youtube, я разрабатываю опираясь на него

Comment: универсального решения сделать нельзя, так как в разных случаях будет разное положение

Comment: @Grundy Вот тут я с тобой не согласен. Ну обычно видео лежит в одном блоке с субтитрами, только на разных уровнях, через jquery есть подобное решение, но оно не подходит как минимум потому что использует jquery. Я придумал решение которое будет в цикле проходится по родителям и проверять children, но проблема в том чем дальше он идёт наверх тем больше придётся проверять детей, а это будет очень затратно. Поэтому надеюсь есть какой-то другой способ.

Comment: @Moonwolf45, ты сам себе противоречишь :-) говоря "обычно" ты указываешь, что иногда оно может лежать вообще где угодно - и тогда найти нужное видео, если на странице их несколько - будет почти невозможно.

Comment: @Grundy нет говоря "обычно" я говорил о том, что других вариантов не видел. И сомневаюсь что они есть.

Comment: @Moonwolf45, они вполне могут быть. Этого достаточно для того, чтобы сказать, что универсального решения быть не может. Может быть только решение для конкретного типа разметки

Comment: Так же ты вполне можешь просто проходиться по всем запущенным видео и складывать их отдельно в коллекцию, тогда проблемы с определением не будет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110449/discussion-between-moonwolf45-and-grundy).

Comment: Ставить на паузу и потом снимать с паузы можно так:
**if (!video[0].paused) {
  video[0].pause();
} else {video[0].play()};**